# Import JSON key containing a no-break space

Tags: json, r

I have a long json file that is generated automatically that contains a no-break space in a JSON key (don't ask my why....). I didn't find a solution to properly import that key+value in R. The no-break space is in the key 'Rain in\u00a0mm\'

Here some reproducible data:

```
#library(jsonlite)
library(rjson)
library (plyr)    
test_data <- fromJSON("[{\"_id\":\"QuWQsXzuqiiAgYM9b\",\"cronjobname\":\"Precip_test\",\"cronjobid\":\"wLbS9XwREnvaChoyu\",\"cronjobtyp\":\"importTestData\",\"datasource\":\"importTestData\",\"data\":[{\"City\":\"New York\",\"Type\":\"Precip\",\"Time\":\"30.04.2016 11:30\",\"Rain in\\u00a0mm\":0}],\"createdAt\":\"2016-05-01T12:10:01.001Z\",\"createdBy\":null,\"modifiedAt\":\"2016-05-01T12:10:01.001Z\",\"modifiedBy\":null}]")
```

I tried replacing all kinds of whitespace with `gsub("[[:space:]]", " ", names(x))` and then let `make.names` automatically generate key names. However, I still can't get the "Rain in mm" key to show up in my dataframe. No matter what I do, only City and Time show up. Any hints on what I'm missing?

```
test <- lapply(test_data[[1]]$data, function(x) {
  x[sapply(x, is.null)] <- NA
  gsub("[[:space:]]", " ", names(x))
  make.names(names(x))
  c(x$City, x$Rain.in.mm, x$Time)
})
test <- ldply (test)
str(test)
```

Here also the code to see what `gsub` and `make.names` do:

```
make.names(names(test_data[[1]]$data[[1]]))
gsub("[[:space:]]", " ", names(test_data[[1]]$data[[1]]))
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to use both `jsonlite` and `rjson` libraries? Usually one is enough. I am using `rjson` and can import your json string without problem.

Comment: I can't reproduce or don't understand the expected result. I am getting `> test_data[[1]]$data[[1]]["Rain in mm"]`    `[1] 0`, which seems correct to me

Comment: Sorry if that caused confusion. Yes it shows the 0 when I call it that way, but I can't use `Rain in\\u00a0mm\` as a column in a dataframe, it simply won't show. So what I want to have is a dataframe with 3 columns City, Rain in mm, Time. Only City and Time appear in the dataframe above.